# Difference between yum update vs yum install

Tags: yum, rpm

While working with the `rpm` command I noticed that if I installed `some-package-1.0` and then performed another `rpm -ivh some-package-1.1` both packages will be listed when I do a `rpm -qa | grep some-package` like the following:

```
some-package-1.0
some-package-1.1
```

However instead of installing 1.1, if I upgrade via the `rpm -Uvh some-package-1.1` I get the desired result of a single package (1.1) when I do `rpm -qa | grep some-package`.

Now does the same behavior apply with `yum install` and `yum update`?

I ask because with the `rpm -U` (upgrade) command a package doesn't have to exist to upgrade/install but with `yum update` (if I'm not mistaken) a package must already exist.

I'm particularly interested to know the result of specifying packages with their versions such as `some-package-1.0`. So in summation, what I want to know is if I have two specific versions such as `some-package-1.0` and `some-package-1.1`:

1. Will performing a `yum install` on 1.1 after 1.0 is already installed, list 2 packages?
2. Will running `yum update some-package-1.1` successfully replace `some-package-1.0`?

Answer (score 35, accepted):

The major differences between YUM and RPM are that `yum` knows how to resolve dependencies and can source these additional packages when doing its work. Though `rpm` can alert you to these dependencies, it is unable to source additional packages.

As to installing vs. upgrading. Both tools can perform an install, and RPM will even allow you to install multiple versions simultaneously, but YUM will tell you that that package is already installed. So no YUM will not allow you to install multiple versions.

As to `yum update`, this will react in one of two ways. If you tell it a package that you want to update, it will attempt to do so, downloading all the necessary dependencies and installing them too. If you run it without any package name, `yum update` will attempt to update *every* package that's installed on your system.

If you use `yum upgrade` it will do the same as `yum update`, except it will attempt to remove any packages that have been marked as "obsolete".

#### Example

Here's a scenario not unlike your own. A new version of `vim-X11` is available.

```
$ yum check-update vim-X11 | expand
Loaded plugins: auto-update-debuginfo, changelog, langpacks, refresh-packagekit

vim-X11.x86_64                     2:7.4.417-1.fc19                      updates
```

And I'm currently at this version:

```
$ rpm -q vim-X11 | expand
vim-X11-7.4.179-1.fc19.x86_64
```

When we try to install it:

```
$ sudo yum install vim-X11
...   
=================================================================================================================================================================
 Package                                 Arch                              Version                                      Repository                          Size
=================================================================================================================================================================
Updating:
 vim-X11                                 x86_64                            2:7.4.417-1.fc19                             updates                            1.2 M
Updating for dependencies:
 vim-common                              x86_64                            2:7.4.417-1.fc19                             updates                            5.9 M
 vim-enhanced                            x86_64                            2:7.4.417-1.fc19                             updates                            1.0 M
....
Running transaction
  Updating   : 2:vim-common-7.4.417-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                            1/6 
  Updating   : 2:vim-enhanced-7.4.417-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                          2/6 
  Updating   : 2:vim-X11-7.4.417-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                               3/6 
  Cleanup    : 2:vim-X11-7.4.179-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                               4/6 
  Cleanup    : 2:vim-enhanced-7.4.179-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                          5/6 
  Cleanup    : 2:vim-common-7.4.179-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                            6/6 
  Verifying  : 2:vim-enhanced-7.4.417-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                          1/6 
  Verifying  : 2:vim-X11-7.4.417-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                               2/6 
  Verifying  : 2:vim-common-7.4.417-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                            3/6 
  Verifying  : 2:vim-enhanced-7.4.179-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                          4/6 
  Verifying  : 2:vim-X11-7.4.179-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                               5/6 
  Verifying  : 2:vim-common-7.4.179-1.fc19.x86_64                                                                                                            6/6
```

#### So in summary

> 1. Will performing a `yum install` on 1.1 after 1.0 is already installed, list 2 packages?

No. YUM will still perform an update even when you've told it to do an install if the package is already installed.

> 2. Will running `yum update some-package-1.1` successfully replace some-package-1.0 ?

Yes.

Comment: Thanks for the much detailed answer. So the way I see it I can just continue to use `yum install` when I specify package name with version and not be concerned with it installing multiple versions. A situation where I would want to use `yum update` would be when I only specify the package name, correct?

Comment: @aspiringCodeArtisan - that's partially correct. `yum install` will detect that a package is already installed and will switch to updating it vs. installing it, as my example showed.

Comment: @slm - To clarify, can rpm search a repository similar to zypper search for a particular package?

Comment: @Motivated - no `rpm` is like `dpkg`, it only concerns itself w/ managing the files on the local disk. For repository "management" b/w your system + a repo you need something like `yum` or `dnf`.

Comment: @slm - If `rpm` and `dpkg` are only concerned with managing files on the local disk, does it limit it to the files on the host or can they still be sourced from locations such as remote filesystems? Secondly, it would suggest that files have to be downloaded. If yes, are there official repositories?

Comment: @Motivated - `rpm` when used to install from a url doesn't do any package dep to pull them in too, it merely downloads the rpm locally and then installs it.

Comment: @slm - Thanks. That makes sense. What are the official repositories for `rpm`?

Comment: @Motivated - it depends. There are many repos that provide RPMs. There's ones that are included into distros like Fedora & CentOS and other 3rd party repos such as EPEL.

Comment: @slm - When you say they are included in the distributions, do you mean on media such as ISOs?

Comment: @Motivated - in `/etc/yum.repo.d` directory are files that point to stock YUM repositories.